# When to use timestamp in sql 2008?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I read several times to convert the timestamp to any readable format but I am not able to decide when to use timestamp datatype or datetime datatype to keep track of records inserted or updated in database in sql server 2008.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`timestamp` is deprecated, do not use this type. Its role has been replaced by the [`rowversion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) type, which is a synonym for timestamp:

> The timestamp syntax is deprecated.
>   This feature will be removed in a
>   future version of Microsoft SQL
>   Server. Avoid using this feature in
>   new development work, and plan to
>   modify applications that currently use
>   this feature.

As a type, `timestamp` (and `rowversion`) has absolutely no relation to dates, time or anything chronological:

> The rowversion data type is just an
>   incrementing number and does not
>   preserve a date or a time.

If you need to track the time when a record was inserted or updated, use  [`DATETIME2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx), at the desired precission.

Answer (score 3):

Read detailed msdn article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx)

hope this will help you.